# control Apache referrer to restrict downloads in htaccess file

Tags: apache-httpd, htaccess

I want to restrict a file server just for people come from an specific URL: `http://graymind.ir`
How should I config `.htaccess` file to do this.

Comment: Please remember that referrer restrictions are only useful for preventing unsophisticated people from accessing a site.  Anyone mildly familiar with HTTP will be able to fake the necessary headers and access the server anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one possibility using the mod_rewrite:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://graymind.ir/.* [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Basically it's checking if the referer starts with `http://graymind.ir/` (non case sensitive), if so then it just rewrites any URL to a `403 Forbidden`

Comment: isn't an "!" at the beginning of ^http... needed?

Comment: He says that he wants to deny requests with that referer. With a `!` it would mean that he wants to deny all except the ones from `graymind.ir`

Comment: my mistake, sorry

Comment: sorry again, i added your code and it works perfect plus an "!" mark, but now it doesn't let download manager get the download link from the main site "graymind.ir", is there any way to fix this?